# ¿ Porque los Divs no se Muestran dentro del DIv?

Tags: php, jquery

El problema es que los DIVS que me da el siclo  no se muestra su texto si no el bloque y fuera del div de Categoria como ven en la imagen

**Index.php**

```
Esto esta dentro de una function yo trabajo con plantillas de php 

//Dentro del cuerpo Usuario
$html .='
        <div id="campoBusq"></div>
            <div id="categoria">';
                include("selectCategJquery.php");

$varHtml .='</div>
       </div>';//Fin del Cuerpo Usuario
```

**selectCategJquery.php**

```
<?php 
    include('../configuracion/conexion.php'); 
?>

<?php 
    $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta) or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

    $contador = 0;
    while ($datosCateorias=$resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $contador++;
        echo "<option class='elemento ".$contador."' iden='".$contador."'>". $datosCateorias['idCategoria']."</option>";
    }



    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    $conexion->close();
?>
    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            $('#categoria').on('click','.elemento',function() {
               var e = $(this).clone();
               var identificador = $(this).attr("iden");

               if($("#campoBusq").find("."+identificador).length){

               }else{
                 $(e).appendTo('#campoBusq');
               } 
           });


            $('#campoBusq').on('click','.elemento',function() {
               $(this).remove();
            });

        });
  </script>
```

**Imagen de la Ejecucion**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque tienes un div cerrado de más -_-

Comment: jajjajajja que despistado, voy a ver 0.o

Comment: por alguna razón tus options ya no se añaden a categoria sino que están flotando libres en el body de tu DOM. Estabas mejor antes usando jQuery.append

Comment: Confirmo. Así como lo tienes no puedes hacer simplemente `echo` del elemento `option` porque esa escritura será inmediata y anterior a la escritura de los contenedores. Vas a tener que usar jQuery.append o modificar la estructura de tu código.

Comment: pero si lo guardo con la misma variable llamada ( $varHtml ) y la concateno desde  selectCategJquery.php ?, no se exactamente como hacer pero busco darle una logica , de como imprimirlo en el selectCategJquery y de una vez meterlo dentro de una variable para que sea la variable que retorne y no el echo...

Comment: Muéstrame cómo usas la variable $html

Comment: Tienes dos variables PHP: una llamada `$html .=` que concatena esto:  `<div id="campoBusq"></div> <div id="categoria">'; include("selectCategJquery.php");` y la otra llamada `$varHtml .=` que concatena esto: `</div> </div>'` Como no veo todo el contenido no sé si tienes dos variables diferentes por algún motivo. Si quieres ver toda esa parte en un mismo lugar, tus valores **no se están concatenando bien.** Si las dos variables mencionadas van juntas debes ponerle el mismo nombre, si van separadas, el div de `$html`
 no está cerrado.

Comment: Está mal, así no se usa el include para lo que necesitas xD!

Comment: abajo esta el trozo  del body donde se encuentra  los divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un div cerrado de más. Quítaselo, debería quedar así:

```
<div id="campoBusq"></div>
<div id="categoria">
     include("selectCategJquery.php");
</div>
```

**EDIT**
En:

```
$varHtml .='</div>
       </div>';
```

Quítale uno:

```
$varHtml .='</div>';
```

**EDIT!!**

No estoy seguro si funcionará pero en teoría sí debería.

Cambia esta parte así:

```
while ($datosCateorias=$resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $contador++;
        $html.= "<option class='elemento ".$contador."' iden='".$contador."'>". $datosCateorias['idCategoria']."</option>";
    }
```

Los optiones concaténaselos a la variable $html donde tienes los divs. No me había fijado como la usabas.

Comment: Dejame ver porque el div fue que me equivoque aqui, supongo; voy atardar en buscar el error, cuando lo termine te aviso men

Comment: No se lo puedes simplemente quitar y ya? xd

Comment: En realidad campoBusq y categoria son dos divs separados, no están uno dentro del otro.

Comment: voy a modificar la pregunta del include

Comment: Es correcto lo que dice @amenadiel. Deja modifico mi respuesta.

Comment: Ya le quite uno nada, sigue igual

Comment: Haz eso que puse en el segundo edit de mi respuesta.

Comment: Biennnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn eso era, habia que guardarlo en la variable $varHtml graciassss a user2930137 y a amenadiel

Comment: Por fin, chinqao! hahahaah Es la importancia de publicar todo el pinche código hahaah. Me da gusto haberte ayudado en todo le recorrido xD Nos vemos. Recuerda poner la respuesta como la buena xd

Comment: Cuando ternine el objetivo lo compartire por aqui para que lo vean muchas graciasss

Comment: Este es un buen ejemplo para los que usan plantillas, espero que lo valoren para que otros aprendan este mismo detalle de las plantillas

Comment: El problema era que tenía dos variables de concatenación: `$html`y `$varHtml` por lo que el contenido no estaba completo (Ver comentario en la pregunta).

Comment: @Gamez, me alegro que al final te haya resultado, pero esta colección de preguntas está muy lejos de ser un ejemplo para trabajar con plantillas. Queda mucho camino por delante.

Comment: @A.Cedano en realidad el problema original era que concatenaba un string con la salida de un include que contenía `echo`. Pero sí, también estaba el tema del nombre de la variable. Eran muchos retazos pegados en el orden incorrecto

Answer (score 0):

```
function body(){
    $varHtml ='<body class="centB">';

        if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])) {
            if (isset($_GET['index']) ) {
                $varHtml .='<header>';
                $varHtml .='
                        <img class="clashImg"src="../fotos/clashofclans_paralax2.jpg">
                        <div id="menu">
                            '.$menu = menu().'
                            <div id="titulo">
                                <img src="../fotos/clashofclans_logo.png">
                                <h2>Trueque</h2>
                            </div>
                            '.$notaPortada = notaPortada().'
                        </div>

                    ';
                $varHtml .='</header>';

                $varHtml .='<div id="cuerpoUsuario">
                                <div class="herramientasMnCont">
                                    <div class="herramientasMn centFRH">

                                        <div class="caj1-HMn1 buscarHMn">
                                            <div class="imgBuscarHMn">
                                                <img src="../css3/fonts_icons/buscar.svg" >
                                            </div>
                                            Buscar Aldeas
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="caj1-HMn1">
                                            <div class="imgBuscarHMn">
                                                <img src="../css3/fonts_icons/vender.svg" >
                                            </div>
                                            Vender Cuenta
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="caj1-HMn1">
                                            <div class="imgBuscarHMn">
                                                <img src="../css3/fonts_icons/cuentasEVenta.svg" >
                                            </div>
                                            Tus Cuentas en Venta
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="caj1-HMn1">
                                            <div class="imgBuscarHMn">
                                                <img src="../css3/fonts_icons/ultimPublicaci.svg" >
                                            </div>
                                            Ultimas Publicaciónes
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>*Aqui esta el problema del Debate*
                                <div id="campoBusq"></div>
                                <div id="categoria">';
                                    include("selectCategJquery.php");

                    $varHtml .='</div>
                            </div>';//Fin del Cuerpo Usuario


            }else{
                $varHtml = '
                    <header>
                        '.$menu = menu().'
                        <div id="subLogo" class="centFRV">
                            <img src="../fotos/clashofclans_logo.png">
                            <h2>Trueque</h2>

                        </div>
                    </header>
                ';
            }
            echo $varHtml;

        } 
            echo $varHtml;


}
```

Comment: el problema esta aqui porque lo Ejecute aparte en documents nuevos y todo esta correcto

Comment: Solo haz lo que dice mi otra respuesta y cambia el echo del while por la variable $html